# Как проверить, было ли значение данных увеличено после нескольких изменений?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, циклы, timestamp

Есть таблица:

```
SalaryChanges (number int (11) not null, 
               salary float(11) not null, 
               dTime timestamp not null, 
               id int (11) not null)
```

Где:

- number - номер записи (pk)
- salary - новое значение зарплаты
- dTime - дата изменения зарплаты
- id - идентификатор работника (fk)

**Вопрос**:
Как получить ID тех работников, зарплата которых увеличилась с 2016 по 2017 год?
(зарплата может меняться ***несколько*** раз и может меняться в отрицательную сторону)

---

Тут можно толковать задачу: 2мя способами:

1. Увеличение между первым и последним изменением зарплаты работника
2. Увеличение между любыми двумя изменениями зарплаты работника

Интересуют оба варианта решения, но №2. предпочтительнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задание недоопределено. Если его понимать, например, так: найти тех, у кого есть данные за оба года, и максимальная зарплата в 2017 году была выше, чем максимальная зарплата в 2016 году, то запрос может быть таким:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM ( SELECT id, MAX(salary) salary2017
       FROM SalaryChanges 
       WHERE YEAR(dTime) = 2017
       GROUP BY id
     ) t1,
     ( SELECT id, MAX(salary) salary2016
       FROM SalaryChanges 
       WHERE YEAR(dTime) = 2016
       GROUP BY id
     ) t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
  AND t1.salary2017 > t2.salary2016
```